# Windows form being locked up by log events spamming listbox log

Tags: c#, multithreading, listbox

I have a listbox event log in my windows form.
Sometimes there are so many events spamming it that the UI becomes locked up and wont accept any user input.

Is it possible to run just the listbox in its own thread and if so, what is a good way to implement that? Or would I have to make a separate form in its own thread that just contains the listbox?

Comment: When you say that it receives events spamming it, what do you mean?  Can you show the code where the `ListBox` is spammed?

Answer (score 0):

Whoops. Found the problem.
There was a

```
Thread.Sleep(50)
```

in the UI thread that should have been in another thread.